# USB or PCI wifi card?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a high internet connection LAN port right beside my PC, but since we five room mates needs to share that, we're planning to buy a wifi router and I'm planning to buy a wifi adapter for my PC. Now, out room is 6m X 6m.

Which adapter going to get me more speed (in LAN my internet goes upto 15 MBPS)?

I don't really need to switch my adapter to any other PC or Laptop all it matters is the speed. And my computer is always downloading something. So, PCI would be a better choice?

In this circumstances, where signal is OK, both provides me the same speed?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried both options, and in fact, sometimes PCI seems to give better performance.

Even if supposedly either version would give you the same max bandwith (54 Mbps for 802.11b and ~540 with 802.11n), my experience is that USB sometimes gets laggy, and soemtimes never reaches the max speed of your internet. I tried with a 20 Mbps connection, and sometimes USB gave me no more than 10 Mb, while PCI always gave me the max speed. (Maybe it was only that the USB adapter may have not been of best quality)

Obviously speed also depends on quality of the signal, proximity to the router, and quality of the adapters themselves. but still my opinion is, unless you have a strong reason to prefer USB, go for PCI.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking at USB 2.0, the theoretical bandwidth of USB is [480 Mbit/s](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://www.everythingusb.com/hi-speed-usb.html&ei=IzT2UJPmJOr3iwKnrYCABQ&usg=AFQjCNEBnlL3RYEiFQEBRfCMoJze46pfmw&sig2=hQq_2xzDRUzildCzvpkPTw&bvm=bv.41018144,d.cGE). 
Assuming you mean PCI and not PCI Express, theoretical bandwidth of PCI is [1,033Mbit/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates#Computer_buses).
So this would suggest PCI is faster.

In reality, neither connection is going to be saturated by WiFi throughput, so speed is not so important.

Whenever given this choice, I always opt for PCI, since I may run out of USB ports later, but I will likely never use up my PCI slots. Also, it's cleaner, since you never have to worry about it falling out of the USB slot.

Answer (score 0):

Though bus band-width should never be fully consumed on either option, ping times (round-trip communication delay between servers) should be lower (better) because of faster timings and connectivity on PCI.